# Xubuntu 19.10 Boot: how to prevent vendors logo from showing all the time?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, 19.10

I recently bought a cheap laptop from Asus (VivoBook S15 X530UF) and I got everything to work quickly as I wanted with Xubuntu 19.10 (except for the laptop lid behavior which I will leave for another thread). During the boot process, with the kernel version 5.3.0-24, the Asus logo appeared only before the GRUB, followed by the plymouth and then the lightdm greeter. And that was it, just like I wanted. Except for a console message regarding the swap partition location which I made disappear after creating a “splash” file with “FRAMEBUFFER=y” in “/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d”.
After the last kernel image update ( 5.3.0-26) the Asus logo started tho show between everything: between grub and the plymouth, between the plymouth and the greeter and even when shutting down, before the plymouth – wich doesn’t happened when booting with version  5.3.0-24. I just don’t like that “ASUS in search of incredible” logo showing all the time. So, after some search I’ve have found [this thread from Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot) and after manually disabling deferred takeover by editing the grub entry:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-26-generic root=UUID=4b59be32-68e7-4a01-98c8-143e880579ca ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff  fbcon=nodefer
```

it stop showing before the greeter and, during shutdown, but it keeps showing between the GRUB and the plymouth, during the boot process. Why, what am I missing here? I would like to understand this a little bit more and, if possible, to have the logo only when I start the computer, before the GRUB menu.

Comment: I can't help, except I've seen a like change recently on sony vaio *crapbook* I use to test Lubuntu 20.04 (etc) on; I've ignored it doesn't impact the QA-testing I do on the *crapbook*, and it doesn't show on desktops (also using 20.04) I do care about.  I assumed was BIOS/UEFI related as 4+ other devices didn't show the behavior.

Comment: I can’t find an option to disable the logo in the BIOS/UEFI but it has to be somehow related to the kernel version change because it didn’t show with vmlinuz-5.3.0-23-generic or  vmlinuz-5.3.0-24-generic. Also, I’m curious to know how  `fbcon=nodefer`  disables FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DEFERRED_TAKEOVER at some stages and not at the others.
On my desktop it doesn’t show either.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the kernel [falling back to the vendor logo](https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/20632.html). I was able to stop the logo from appearing between GRUB and Plymouth [in Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/668654/423679) by adding `video=efifb:nobgrt` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`. Considering that it is a Linux kernel console parameter, it should work for Ubuntu too. (Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after changing `/etc/default/grub`.)